# How to sum fields depending on the other column on iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two columns like

```
ITP,VPVP
250,10
330,10
255,20
565,10
84,20....

$F(ITP)
$F(VPVP)
```

How can I sum values where VPVP 10 and where the value of VPVP 20 is?

For example, in the report

```
The sum for 10 is: 1145     (250+330+565 -  This should not be written)
The sum for 20 is: 339      (255+84 - This should not be written)
```

I tried something like this but it's not good:

```
<variable name="The sum for 10 is:" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["10".equals($F{VPVP})?$F{ITP}:$V{zero}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

Comment: Replace `$V{zero}` to `new BigDecimal(0)`.

Comment: When I replace it, I get it  0

Comment: What is the type of `$F{VPVP}`?

Comment: java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: Try `new BigDecimal("10").compareTo($F{VPVP})==0?$F{ITP}:new BigDecimal(0)`.

Comment: if it means something to you:
Text field expression for VPVP:
$F{VPVP} == null ? "" : new java.text.DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0.00").format( ($F{VPVP}).doubleValue() )

Comment: nothing again 0

Comment: If you are using "###,###,###,##0.00" for `VPVP` , it shows 10.00 or other value?

Comment: i create new variable $V{oo}

`$V{oo} == null ? java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO : ($F{ITP}).compareTo(new java.math.BigDecimal(20.00)) == 0 ? $F{VPVP} : new BigDecimal(0)`